# Choosing an appropriate Zend Framework exception class

Tags: zend-framework

Using Zend Framework, I want to throw an exception inside a particular method in my model class if there are arguments passed that are considered illegal for that method. In Java, for example, I would do something like this:

```
public void addName(String name) {
 if (name.equals('')) {
  throw new IllegalArgumentException();
 }
 // Other code if everything is ok.
}
```

However, as far as I can see, PHP and Zend Framework lack such basic built-in exception classes like `IllegalArgumentException`. So what should I use to properly pass an exception that actually describes what went wrong? Create such exception class myself? But isn't it this kind of code what a framework is supposed to eliminate?

I'm just starting learning Zend Framework. I haven't wrote a lot of PHP in my life so please feel free to explain me some things that you think should be obvious for a decent PHP programmer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the list of available exceptions in the [PHP SPL exception class](http://www.php.net/manual/en/spl.exceptions.php).

```
Exception
     LogicException
         BadFunctionCallException
         BadMethodCallException
         DomainException
         InvalidArgumentException
         LengthException
         OutOfRangeException
     RuntimeException
         OutOfBoundsException
         OverflowException
         RangeException
         UnderflowException
         UnexpectedValueException
```

Zend Framework's `Zend_Exception` is just a wrapper for PHP's built in exceptions, however most of the major components have a callable exception class.

for example:

```
public function setId($id)
    {
        $validator = new My_Validator_Id();
        if ($validator->isValid($id)) {
            $this->id = $id;
            return $this;
        } else {
            throw new Zend_Validate_Exception("$id is not a valid value for the ID field.");
        }
    }
```

or with PHP's built in excepition:

```
public function __get($name)
    {
        $property = strtolower($name);

        if (!property_exists($this, $property)) {
            throw new \InvalidArgumentException(
                "Getting the property '$property' is not valid for this entity");
        }
        //truncated...
    }
```

Zend Framework 2 has even more specific `exceptions` available.